# JMeter: Low CPU usage but response too low

Tags: web-services, jmeter, load, cpu, seconds

I am trying to load test for web services with 1000 Users using JMeter. I can see CPU usage is around 30% once 1000 Users are injected but when it comes to response, maximum time taken is around 12 Seconds.

My query is, if the CPU is not utilized 100%, maximum time in receiving any response should not get more than few seconds.

Comment: How many CPU cores?

Comment: Single Core Processor

Comment: Impossible to say due to no information about what the system does. If it's IO bound this will easily happen.

Comment: Its just a web service to fetch some details.

Comment: How much JVM heap that you are using for JMeter? Which garbage collection algorithm are you using while running JMeter? Please can you post a snapshot of your full result CSV file showing latency, elapsed and connect times?

Answer (score 1):

1. It is good that you are monitoring CPU usage on application server side. However the devil may live somewhere else, for instance application can experience the lack of available RAM, does intensive [swapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging#Terminology) or reaches the limits of network or disk IO so you should consider these metrics as well. Aforementioned ones (and more) can be monitored using [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test).
2. Basically the same as point 1, but applied to JMeter side of things. JMeter tests are very resource intensive and if JMeter lacks resources it will be sending requests much slower. So make sure you monitor baseline OS health metrics on JMeter machine(s) as well. Also 1000 users is quite a high load, double check you test corresponds [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)
3. It may be the bottleneck in your application, i.e. it isn't capable of providing a good response time given 1000 concurrent users. Use the relevant [profiler tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)) to detect the most long running functions and investigate the root cause.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, above points are really helpful. Would like to inform you that Memory is 1GB. I am using AWS EC2, t2.micro for monitoring CPU.